# freeze tkinter when I use pyserial

Tags: python, tkinter, freeze, pyserial

I have a problem with this code, I'm new in python and the problem is this: I need receive some datas from arduino in a Python GUI, I receive the data and is saved in a txt file but my programa freeze and I can´t return to my main window.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
from sys import *
import serial
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfile

v0=Tk() 
v0.config(bg="mintcream")                              
v0.geometry("400x300")                                 
v0.title("INFORMATION")
label1=Label(v0, text="INFORMATION",font=("Arial", 18,"bold"), fg= "black", bg="mint cream", anchor=W, justify="center").pack()

def ejecutar(f): v0.after(200,f)            

def recepcion(v0):
       ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1.0)
       i=0
       while i <= 1000:
              archivo = open('DATA BASE.txt', 'a')
              archivo.write(ser.readline())
              archivo.close()

              i= i+1
       ser.close()

def procesar(v0):
       with open("DATA BASE.txt") as fichero:
              for linea in fichero:
                     print (linea)

##Button
b4=Button(v0,text="RECEIVE DATA", font=("Arial", 8, "bold"), bg=("medium sea green"), command=lambda:recepcionIMPEDANCIA(v0))   
b4.pack()                         
b4.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=50, width=110, relx=0.05, rely=0.4)

v0.mainloop()
```

Comment: you should do your serial communication in a separate process or thread ... if you do it in your main thread than yes it will block ...

Comment: do you have any example?

Comment: there are many examples on google ... its going to be a little painful (tkinter has no "call in main thread" method ... wx/qt work better)  ... just make sure you update the tkinter gui only in the main thread .... it will take far to much to provide a simple example for you